# wordpress login form on the header

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication, header

Please help me, how to add a login form on the header like fb on the wordpress pleas thanks.. I tried the form below and added it to the header page but it's not working;

```
<?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" />
         <p>
               <label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
               <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <h2>Logout</h2>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">logout</a><br />
        <a href="http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/">admin</a>
        <?php }?>
```

---

I tried to add it to my header-login.php and header.php `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` but still not showing up or not working

Comment: "it's not working" is hardly ever enough to describe a problem. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the full login form, you don't need to code in a new form. Just use the <kbd>[wp_login_form()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)</kbd> function.

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```